# minikube service list returns empty URL

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

minikube service list -p multinode-demo returns empty URL on macOS Sonoma Apple M1 Pro.

Please refer to the terminal output.
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.0
BuildVersion:       23A344
arch: arm64

docker version Client:
Cloud integration: v1.0.35
Version:           24.0.2
API version:       1.43
Go version:        go1.20.4
Git commit:        cb74dfc
Built:             Thu May 25 21:51:16 2023
OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
Context:           desktop-linux

minikube version: minikube version: v1.31.2

**Terminal Output**

```
% minikube start --nodes 2 -p multinode-demo
  [multinode-demo] minikube v1.31.2 on Darwin 14.0 (arm64)
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver
  Using Docker Desktop driver with root privileges
  Starting control plane node multinode-demo in cluster multinode-demo
  Pulling base image ...
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.27.4 on Docker 24.0.4 ...
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
    ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
  Configuring CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass

  Starting worker node multinode-demo-m02 in cluster multinode-demo
  Pulling base image ...
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Found network options:
    ▪ NO_PROXY=192.168.49.2
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.27.4 on Docker 24.0.4 ...
    ▪ env NO_PROXY=192.168.49.2
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "multinode-demo" cluster and "default" namespace by default
% kubectl get nodes
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
multinode-demo       Ready    control-plane   36s   v1.27.4
multinode-demo-m02   Ready    <none>          17s   v1.27.4
% minikube status -p multinode-demo
multinode-demo
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

multinode-demo-m02
type: Worker
host: Running
kubelet: Running

% cat hello-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 100%
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      affinity:
        # ⬇⬇⬇ This ensures pods will land on separate hosts
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions: [{ key: app, operator: In, values: [hello] }]
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
        - name: hello-from
          image: pbitty/hello-from:latest
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1
% kubectl apply -f hello-deployment.yaml
deployment.apps/hello created
% kubectl rollout status deployment/hello
deployment "hello" successfully rolled out
% cat hello-svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
% kubectl apply -f hello-svc.yaml
service/hello created
% kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-77c947d946-5lmdh   1/1     Running   0          38s
pod/hello-77c947d946-hrb9f   1/1     Running   0          38s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/hello        NodePort    10.103.213.243   <none>        80:31000/TCP   8s
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        2m13s

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/hello   2/2     2            2           38s

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/hello-77c947d946   2         2         2       38s
% kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                 NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
hello-77c947d946-5lmdh   1/1     Running   0          48s   10.244.0.3   multinode-demo       <none>           <none>
hello-77c947d946-hrb9f   1/1     Running   0          48s   10.244.1.2   multinode-demo-m02   <none>           <none>
% minikube service list -p multinode-demo
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----|
|  NAMESPACE  |    NAME    | TARGET PORT  | URL |
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----|
| default     | hello      |           80 |     |
| default     | kubernetes | No node port |     |
| kube-system | kube-dns   | No node port |     |
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----|
% minikube profile list
|----------------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|--------|
|    Profile     | VM Driver | Runtime |      IP      | Port | Version | Status  | Nodes | Active |
|----------------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|--------|
| multinode-demo | docker    | docker  | 192.168.49.2 | 8443 | v1.27.4 | Running |     2 |        |
|----------------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|--------|
```